# How to gracefully interrupt blocking waits in Windows?

Tags: java, c++, windows, java-native-interface

I need to write a JNI interface that performing blocking I/O operations And I need these methods can be interrupted. For example:

```
interface IO {
  native void waitForEvents() throws InterruptedException, IOException;
  native int readBytes(byte[] data, int offset, int len) throws InterruptedException, IOException;
 }
```

And on Win32, I use windows API 'waitForSingleObject(HADLE)' to implements "waitForEvents", and 'read(HANDLE)' to implements 'readBytes'.

How can I interrupt the blocking functions 'waitForSingleObject' and 'read'?

Comment: Really a Windows API question, not Java or JNI at all.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to look at the `java.nio` channel classes to learn how to do non-blocking Java IO, rather than getting tangled up in JNI.

Answer (score 0):

To unblock the call you likely want another thread to signal the handle the orig thread is blocking for.  Perhaps create another JNI call for that purpose.